# Cannot change file permission via FTP: '500 - command not understood'

Tags: web-hosting, ftp, chmod

I have an old site that is in danger of being compromised as many of the directories and files have permissions set to 777. However, when I try to change them to 555 via FileZilla I get the error

> 500 'SITE CHMOD 555 filename': command not understood

Googling it only reveals issues relevant to connecting to the server, but I can do that, as well as up and downloading files. I'm not sure what this means exactly. Is it that my account doesn't have sufficient permissions to make these changes?

Comment: Do you have SSH access?

Comment: @Riboflavin no, just FTP

Comment: Are you on a Windows server? `chmod` is a unix command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better change the permissions either via your File manager( which should be available in your control panel) or directly via SSH access by using the chmod command.

Comment: As w3d pointed out in his comment, chmod, a UNIX/LINUX command is not available on a Windows Host.  FileZilla uses the chmod command, and AFAIK, there is no equivalent in Windows.  The control Panel in Plesk I assume is akin to the Security Tab of the Properties Window in Windows, which is why you are able to "via the control panel"

Answer (score 0):

It is likely caused by your web host disallowing the chmod command over FTP. If you have a control panel available through your host I would use that to try to change the folder permissions and see if it works that way.